# Running a .exe program using Python

Tags: python, executable

Little background:
Code::Blocks is an IDE with a C++ integrated compiler. When creating a C++ project, it creates a .exe file so you can run the project.

So now I want to run that executable file using a Python script (Using VSCode). I tried subprocess.call(), subprocess.run() and subprocess.Popen(), and all of them start the background process, but it doesn't compile, so it just keeps running on the Task Manager. If I run it manually (by double-clicking it) then it opens, it closes and I get my correct answer on the output file.

This is the C++ project folder for the problem "kino" :
[image]

This is a photo with the .exe on the Task Manager :
[image]

And this is my Python code:

```
process = subprocess.run([r'C:\Users\Documents\kino\kino.exe'], shell = True)
```

I want to say that I also tried subprocess.kill(), but it should terminate on its own (and I don't get my answer).

Edit:
[Here is a video describing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTbmA.jpg)

Comment: What happens when you run subprocess.call([r'C:\Users\Documents\kino\kino.exe']) ? I think it would be the right choice

Comment: What does kino.exe do?  Could it be waiting for input on stdin?  Maybe it works differently depending on if its stdin is connected to a console or not?

Comment: The same thing happens when I run subprocess.call(), but the program freezes until I close the executable.

Comment: I have a .in file (for input), a .out file (for output), the main.cpp file (which contains the c++ code) and the executable. The executable takes the input from the .in file, runs it using the .cpp file and prints the answer on the .out file. Should I post a small clip of how it works?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just do it with subprocess

`import subprocess
subprocess.call(["C:\\Users\\Documents\\kino\\kino.exe"])`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running a subprocess you could execute the program with msdos commands:

```
import os
os.system('C:\Users\Documents\kino\kino.exe')
```

The only problem is that this will block your python script until the .exe program stops running.

Comment: Same thing happens... The program executes but it runs in the background and it doesn't stop.

Comment: use subprocess.Popen()